# KonvaJS: How to get a scaled & moved layer's position based on current mouse position?

Tags: konvajs

here's my Konva object design: One stage that includes two layers. One layer is a toolbar that I drag and drop shapes from, one layer is a canvas that I drop the elements in. The canvas layer can be zoomed in and out and is draggable (relative zoomed feature implemented from lavtron's demos https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Zooming_Relative_To_Pointer.html).

When the user drops a shape from the toolbar, a new shape gets added to the canvas layer and should have the same position as to where the user eyeballed it. So before I put zooming into my program, the only concern was to modify the position according to layer's offset by: 
`toPush.x = toPush.x - this.refs.layer2.attrs.x; //toPush.x = Stage mouseX position
toPush.y = toPush.y - this.refs.layer2.attrs.y; //toPush.y = Stage mouseY position`

I used lavtron's zooming based on mouse position which scales and shifts the layer in order to achieve the effect.

My react code looks like:

```
<Stage ...>
<Layer onWheel={this.onWheel} x={this.state.layerX} y={this.state.layerY} >
... all the shapes...
</Layer>
</Stage>

  onWheel = () => {
  const scaleBy = 1.1;
    const stage = this.refs.graphicStage;
    const layer = this.refs.layer2;
    const oldScale = layer.scaleX();
    const mousePointTo = {
      x: stage.getPointerPosition().x / oldScale - this.state.layerX / oldScale,
      y: stage.getPointerPosition().y / oldScale - this.state.layerY / oldScale
    };

    const newScale =
      event.evt.deltaY < 0 ? oldScale * scaleBy : oldScale / scaleBy;

    layer.scale({ x: newScale, y: newScale });
      this.setState({
    layerScale: newScale,
     layerX:
    -(mousePointTo.x - stage.getPointerPosition().x / newScale) * newScale,
     layerY:
    -(mousePointTo.y - stage.getPointerPosition().y / newScale) * newScale
});
}
```

But after implementing zooming, when I drag and drop shapes, they don't land in where I eyeballed, and interestingly, as the location I dropped them gets further away from (x:0,y:0), the more they will shift towards (0,0).

Here's the most reasonable code I have tried to calculate the new position in order to make the objects land where they were supposed to drop.

1. `toPush.x = toPush.x - this.state.layerX; //this.state.layerX = layer's X offset
   toPush.y = toPush.y - this.state.layerY;`

   2.
   `toPush.x = toPush.x - (this.state.layerX) * layer's scale; 
   toPush.y = toPush.y - this.state.layerY * layer's scale;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this demo to calculate relative position: https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Relative_Pointer_Position.html

With `react-konva` it may look something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Stage, Layer, Circle } from "react-konva";

const App = () => {
  const [localPos, setPos] = React.useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const layerRef = React.useRef();

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      Try to move the mouse over stage
      <Stage
        width={window.innerWidth}
        height={window.innerHeight}
        onMouseMove={e => {
          var transform = layerRef.current.getAbsoluteTransform().copy();
          // to detect relative position we need to invert transform
          transform.invert();
          // now we find relative point
          const pos = e.target.getStage().getPointerPosition();
          var circlePos = transform.point(pos);

          setPos(circlePos);
        }}
      >
        <Layer x={50} y={50} scaleX={0.5} scaleY={2} ref={layerRef}>
          <Circle radius={50} fill="green" x={localPos.x} y={localPos.y} />
        </Layer>
      </Stage>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-relative-pos-demo-k6num